# Bootstrap: responsive button in grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what I wanted to do in wide screen:
[image]

, where buttons are right side and located in one line.

Those are supposed to located in small screen like this:
[image]

, where button are separated in each rows

I think that I could implement this with `bootstrap` grid system, but kinda hard to implement this.

Here is what I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-2">
        <a href="#" id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-primary"  style=" margin-right:5px; background-color:#313131; border-color:#313131;"> 주문 취소 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-2">
        <a href="#" id="edit-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style=" margin-left:5px;"> 주문 수정 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But doesn't work. Need helps. Thanks.

Comment: "Doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you want, but I guessed what you want. 
Do you want to show like this?

You can see here 
[an example](http://jsbin.com/gazobuwavo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add change col-sm-2 class to **col-sm-12** (will extend on small screen)
and add class **col-lg-2**
also set offset to lg screen

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-8 col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
        <a href="#" id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-primary"  style=" margin-right:5px; background-color:#313131; border-color:#313131;"> 주문 취소 </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2">
        <a href="#" id="edit-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style=" margin-left:5px;"> 주문 수정 </a>
    </div>
</div>
```